# Develop Java like PHP

Tags: maven, tomcat

I am developing a web application with spring mvc on eclipce under linux.
What i want to do is to get to a point that i can save a java file and just refresh the browser to get the results, like PHP.
Right now, I have my tomcat configured with hot deploy (which helps).
For the js + html side i have configured allowLinking so this side is working
But i still need to "mvn install" every java change.
Any suggestions how to make the development faster?

(Looking for automation and not to skip the native JVM proccess.)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/).

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, your JVM needs a restart or reload the context (at the least) for the changes to be reflected, even if you copy over the .class files manually.

Comment: I know, and I dont want to skip that. looking for automation inside the eclipce